# How to mock django.db.connection.schema_name

Tags: django, django-testing, python-mock

I am trying to test a multi-tenant django app.  I'm trying to mock a connection to the public tenant:

```
class ViewsTest(ViewTestUtilsMixin, TenantTestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.factory = RequestFactory()

    def test_some_public_only_view(self)
         # generate a request instance so we can call our view directly
        request = self.factory.get('/')

        with patch('tenant.views.connection.schema_name', return_value=get_public_schema_name()):
            response = some_public_only_view(request)  
            self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

However, when I debug this to check the value of schema_name in the `some_public_only_view` method during the test, I get this:

`<MagicMock name='schema_name' id='140578910478880'>`,

so at least I know I'm patching the correct location.  The problem is that `schema_name` is not a method, so it doesn't use the return value.

So how can I mock the `schema_name`?  The view being testing is using it in this way in **tenant/views.py**

```
def some_public_only_view(request):

    if connection.schema_name == get_public_schema_name():
         # do stuff
         # returns a good view, 200
    else:
         raise Http404
```

I also tried this:

```
with patch.object('tenant.views.connection', 'schema_name', get_public_schema_name()):
```

which gives me: `AttributeError: tenant.views.connection does not have the attribute 'schema_name'`

Comment: how does the `tenant.views.connection.schema_name` looks like?

Comment: What will be the value of `connection.schema_name` if you set `return_value='some-foo-bar'` ?

Comment: in **tenant/views.py** it is being imported with `from django.db import connection` and used like this:  `if connection.schema_name == get_public_schema_name():`

Comment: If I set `return_value='some-foo-bar'` I still get `<MagicMock name='schema_name' id='140550783721584'>`  if I inspect it with `print(connection.schema_name)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mock an object property using `PropertyMock` in this way:

```py
@patch('tenant.views.connection.schema_name', new_callable=PropertyMock(return_value="abc"))
def test_some_public_only_view(self, mock_schema):
...
```

here the documentation https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.PropertyMock

Anyway, there is nothing wrong with your approach, in fact, I've also tested your code:

```py
with patch.object('tenant.views.connection', 'schema_name', get_public_schema_name()):
```

and I didn't get any error.

I've experienced this error `AttributeError: tenant.views.connection does not have the attribute 'schema_name'` when I tried first without having set up the right database backend, that should come from the `tenant_schemas` library, one of these: `postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'`, I've used `tenant_schemas.postgresql_psycopg2`

If this is the reason (database settings misconfiguration), if you try to run your test without patching `schema_name`, you should have this error

```py
AttributeError: 'DatabaseWrapper' object has no attribute 'schema_name'
```

as mentioned here: https://github.com/bernardopires/django-tenant-schemas/issues/328

Comment: I'll try the PropertyMock, thanks. I don't get any errors if I don't patch. I'm using `tenant_schemas.postgresql_backend` and `tenant_schemas.routers.TenantSyncRouter`